# iOS 6 Segemented Control custom tint colors

Tags: ios6, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

Below is the code that I'm using in my app for a custom segmented control with on/off colors. However, with iOS 6, when the view first loads it is the default colors. Once you choose one of the segments, then the proper custom colors appear. What do I need to do to have it appear when the view loads and ensure it's compatible for devices not on iOS 6.

```
#define kTagFirst 111
#define kTagSecond 112
#define kTagThird 113

- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender
{
  UIColor *darkBG = [UIColor colorWithRed:149.0/255.0 green:133.0/255.0 blue:115.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
  UIColor *lightBG = [UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:232.0/255.0 blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
  UIColor *darkText = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:72.0/255.0 blue:60.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
  UIColor *lightText = [UIColor whiteColor];

  [segmentedControl setTintColor:darkBG forTag:kTagFirst];
  [segmentedControl setTintColor:darkBG forTag:kTagSecond];
  [segmentedControl setTintColor:darkBG forTag:kTagThird];
//  [segmentedControl setTextColor:lightText forTag:kTagFirst];
//  [segmentedControl setTextColor:lightText forTag:kTagSecond];
//  [segmentedControl setTextColor:lightText forTag:kTagThird];

  switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
  {
    case 0:
      mapView.hidden = YES;
      infoView.hidden = YES;
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:darkBG forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:lightBG forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:lightBG forTag:kTagThird];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:lightText forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:darkText forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:darkText forTag:kTagThird];
      //[segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagThird];
      break;
    case 1:
      mapView.hidden = NO;
      infoView.hidden = YES;
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:lightBG forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:darkBG forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:lightBG forTag:kTagThird];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:darkText forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:lightText forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:darkText forTag:kTagThird];
      [segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagFirst];
      //[segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagThird];
      break;
    case 2:
      mapView.hidden = YES;
      infoView.hidden = NO;
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:lightBG forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:lightBG forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setTintColor:darkBG forTag:kTagThird];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:darkText forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:darkText forTag:kTagSecond];
      [segmentedControl setTextColor:lightText forTag:kTagThird];
      [segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagFirst];
      [segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagSecond];
      //[segmentedControl setShadowColor:lightBG forTag:kTagThird];
      break;
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
  [segmentedControl setTag:kTagFirst forSegmentAtIndex:2];
  [segmentedControl setTag:kTagSecond forSegmentAtIndex:1];
  [segmentedControl setTag:kTagThird forSegmentAtIndex:0];
  [self segmentedControlChanged:nil];

  mapView.hidden = YES;
  infoView.hidden = YES;
  segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to move some logic into view did load method that sets the default tint color for your segment bar on load.  right now, you have all that logic in your IBAction - which probably does not get called until it is first selected.

hope that helps

Comment: That's what is at the bottom of the code I thought under the ViewDidLoad. Is that not enough for it to know? Thanks for your help!